# Is expectation finite almost surely or not almost surely?

Tags: martingales, conditional-expectation

Let $\{w_n\}$ be a sequence of non-negative numbers and $\{X_n,\mathcal{F}_n, n\ge 1\}$ be a uniformly bounded martingale differences. Put
$M_n= \sum_{k=1}^n w_k^2 <\infty$. I solved that
\begin{align*}  \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \mathbb{E} \left( \left| w_n X_n \right|^2 | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}   \right) =\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left[  |w_n|^2 \mathbb{E} \left( \left|X_n \right|^2 | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}   \right) \right] &= \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left[  |w_n|^2 \mathbb{E} \left( X_n^2    \right) \right] \text{(by independence)} \\
   &\le  c^2 \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty    |w_{n}|^2 <\infty \text{ almost surely}.  
\end{align*}
Is this right? Is it finite almost surely or not almost surely?

Comment: You can get proper spacing by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion.

Comment: $M_n$ is trivially finite since it is a finite sum of non-negative real numbers. Did you mean that $\sup_n M_n<\infty$? If that is the case, and by "uniformly bounded" you mean that $\sup_n \mathbb E[X_n^2]<\infty$, then yes, your argument is correct.